# Better approach than to create new tables for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

Tables of old data:

[image]

I was wondering if there were other ways to optimize this or if there's a different approach of linking these 2 tables together somehow.

For my first project this was how I approached it (years ago), now that I've encountered a somewhat similar problem I was wondering if what I did before was the best... because I'm somehow having doubts (somewhat having a gut feeling that I'm doing it wrong). I haven't done SQL for quite some time so my thought process doesn't seem to be doing that well for this problem.

Tables of current data:

[image]

My problem is that the processes of how to create the products aren't the same as how the other products are made, and that the time to accomplish the tasks/proccesses aren't the same either.

So my question, again, is that is this the best way to solve this? If not, would you mind sharing some insight as to how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Normalisation isn’t the easiest concept to grasp, but a couple of hours with a decent textbook or tutorial should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Alright, I'll go review and give it a shot, I know the concept but there may be some specifics that I guess I'm missing.

Comment: So I guess what's going to happen is to have unique identifiers with the cross-referenced data producing a single massive (denormalized) table (A001I001, A001I002)? Then when I query the specific areas, I just use the appropriate area ID in my filter (A001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating separate tables for each product is a bad design.
If you have 10000 products, you have to have 10001 tables, it's nightmare. A few  drawbacks:

- it is expected to be slow
- if you want to add a new column to this structure you need to alter 10000 tables
- some very basic queries against this schema are practically immposibile to write, for example *give me all products where Melting proccess is 1:00* or *Give me an average time of Casting process for all products*

---

This is usually solved creating only 2 tables and using [Foreign Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)


A very simple example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8175b/4 (it is scrappy - wrong datatypes, missing indexes, missing constraints etc. but shows the idea):

```
CREATE TABLE product(
   pid int primary key,
   ProductName varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO product VALUES
( 1, 'Earning001' ),( 2, 'Earning002' ),( 3, 'Necklerace001' );

CREATE TABLE Times(
  product_pid int,
  process varchar(100) not null,
  timetoaccomplish varchar(10) not null,
  constraint times_pid_kf foreign key (product_pid) references product(pid)
);

INSERT INTO Times VALUES
(1, 'Melting', '1:00'),(1, 'Casting', '2:00'),(1, 'Polishing', '0:20'),
(2, 'Melting', '1:20'),(2, 'Casting', '1:30'),(2, 'Polishing', '0:40'),
(3, 'Melting', '5:20'),(3, 'Casting', '2:15'),(3, 'Polishing', '1:45');
```

---

```
select * from Product;

| pid |   ProductName |
|-----|---------------|
|   1 |    Earning001 |
|   2 |    Earning002 |
|   3 | Necklerace001 |
```

---

```
select * from Times;

| product_pid |   process | timetoaccomplish |
|-------------|-----------|------------------|
|           1 |   Melting |             1:00 |
|           1 |   Casting |             2:00 |
|           1 | Polishing |             0:20 |
|           2 |   Melting |             1:20 |
|           2 |   Casting |             1:30 |
|           2 | Polishing |             0:40 |
|           3 |   Melting |             5:20 |
|           3 |   Casting |             2:15 |
|           3 | Polishing |             1:45 |
```

---

```
select * 
from product p
join Times t
on p.pid = t.product_pid;

| pid |   ProductName | product_pid |   process | timetoaccomplish |
|-----|---------------|-------------|-----------|------------------|
|   1 |    Earning001 |           1 |   Melting |             1:00 |
|   1 |    Earning001 |           1 |   Casting |             2:00 |
|   1 |    Earning001 |           1 | Polishing |             0:20 |
|   2 |    Earning002 |           2 |   Melting |             1:20 |
|   2 |    Earning002 |           2 |   Casting |             1:30 |
|   2 |    Earning002 |           2 | Polishing |             0:40 |
|   3 | Necklerace001 |           3 |   Melting |             5:20 |
|   3 | Necklerace001 |           3 |   Casting |             2:15 |
|   3 | Necklerace001 |           3 | Polishing |             1:45 |
```

---

And a simple query: *Give me all products where process is Casting and time is at least 2:00*

```
select * 
from product p
join Times t
on p.pid = t.product_pid
WHERE t.process = 'Casting'
  AND t.timetoaccomplish >= '2:00'

| pid |   ProductName | product_pid | process | timetoaccomplish |
|-----|---------------|-------------|---------|------------------|
|   1 |    Earning001 |           1 | Casting |             2:00 |
|   3 | Necklerace001 |           3 | Casting |             2:15 |
```

Comment: Okay, so I guess having something like a unique key for processXtime is the way to go (or should I even make it ItemXProcessXTime?). It does look better than altering the schema every time there's a new material or a new process.